# How to rollback ffmpeg version to desired version? Is rollback needed in this scenario?

Tags: 16.04, webcam, ffmpeg, arm

This is a ubuntu 16.04 running on armhf board.

I use ffmpeg for recording video from webcam. The process kind of works best in a version of the ffmpeg. I want to install/rollback to the particular version.

Output from clone that has issues :

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-indev=v4l2
libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
libavcodec     58. 42.104 / 58. 42.104
libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100


root@busplay4:/usr/bin# dpkg-query -W ffmpeg
ffmpeg  5:201812261919-git-1
root@busplay4:/usr/bin# dpkg -l | grep ffmpeg
ii  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra           71.0.3578.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                armhf        Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
ii  ffmpeg                                 5:201812261919-git-1                         armhf        Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2
ii  ffmpeg-doc                             7:3.3.3-5ubuntu1                             all          Documentation of the FFmpeg multimedia framework
ii  ffmpegthumbnailer                      2.0.10-0.1                                   armhf        fast and lightweight video thumbnailer
ii  libavcodec-ffmpeg56:armhf              7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with de/encoders for audio/video codecs - runtime files
ii  libavdevice-ffmpeg56:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for handling input and output devices - runtime files
ii  libavfilter-ffmpeg5:armhf              7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library containing media filters - runtime files
ii  libavformat-ffmpeg56:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with (de)muxers for multimedia containers - runtime files
ii  libavresample-ffmpeg2:armhf            7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg compatibility library for resampling - runtime files
ii  libavutil-ffmpeg54:armhf               7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with functions for simplifying programming - runtime files
ii  libffmpegthumbnailer4v5                2.0.10-0.1                                   armhf        shared library for ffmpegthumbnailer
ii  libpostproc-ffmpeg53:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for post processing - runtime files
ii  libswresample-ffmpeg1:armhf            7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for audio resampling, rematrixing etc. - runtime files
ii  libswscale-ffmpeg3:armhf               7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for image scaling and various conversions - runtime files
```

Output from working clone :

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.3.3-5ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 20160904
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=5ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --enable-v4l2_m2m --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
```

These two XU4s were clones, we somehow managed to changed the version to the newer one through some make/build. We dont have information on how we ended up with a different version. How do we rollback or change to the preferred version. The reason to rollback is that the performance of the video recording using ffmpeg is better in the previous version.

Output from clone that works fine. The  3.3.3-5ubuntu1 version.

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.3-5ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 20160904
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=5ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --enable-v4l2_m2m --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=5ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --enable-v4l2_m2m --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-netcdf
  avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=5ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --enable-v4l2_m2m --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-netcdf
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x645ec0] The V4L2 driver changed the video from 320x240 to 640x480
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x645ec0] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/30 to 1/60
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 16103.299011, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Codec AVOption x264opts (x264 options) specified for output file #0 (lq4.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (h264_v4l2m2m))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x67c9f0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] driver 'uvcvideo' on card '3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] driver 'exynos-gsc' on card 'exynos-gsc gscaler'
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] driver 's5p-mfc' on card 's5p-mfc-enc'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] Using device /dev/video11
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] driver 's5p-mfc' on card 's5p-mfc-enc'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] h264_v4l2m2m encoder: enabling bit rate control: 750000
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] h264 profile not found
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] Encoder adjusted: qmin (0), qmax (51)
Output #0, mp4, to 'lq4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_v4l2m2m) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), nv21, 640x480, q=2-31, 750 kb/s, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 h264_v4l2m2m
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x649940] output  POLLERR
[mp4 @ 0x648400] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  737 fps= 61 q=-0.0 Lsize=    2561kB time=00:00:12.25 bitrate=1712.3kbits/s dup=153 drop=0 speed=1.02x   
video:2557kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.153437%
```

Output from the version that doesnt work :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 320x240 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt nv21 -vcodec h264 -acodec none -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1 -b:v 750k -minrate 750k -maxrate 750k -bufsize 1000k lq4.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-indev=v4l2
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
  libavcodec     58. 42.104 / 58. 42.104
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x16f4390] The V4L2 driver changed the video from 320x240 to 640x480
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x16f4390] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/30 to 1/60
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 375.645303, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Codec AVOption x264opts (x264 options) specified for output file #0 (lq4.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (h264_v4l2m2m))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1706dd0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x16f8490] driver 'uvcvideo' on card '3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x16f8490] driver 'exynos-gsc' on card 'exynos-gsc gscaler'
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x16f8490] driver 's5p-mfc' on card 's5p-mfc-enc'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x16f8490] Using device /dev/video11
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x16f8490] driver 's5p-mfc' on card 's5p-mfc-enc'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x16f8490] h264 profile not found
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x16f8490] Encoder adjusted: qmin (0), qmax (51)
Output #0, mp4, to 'lq4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_v4l2m2m) (avc1 / 0x31637661), nv21, 640x480, q=2-31, 750 kb/s, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.42.104 h264_v4l2m2m
[mp4 @ 0x16f7050] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mjpeg @ 0x16f5c90] mjpeg_decode_dc: bad vlc: 0:0 (0x16f626c)
[mjpeg @ 0x16f5c90] error dc
[mjpeg @ 0x16f5c90] error y=41 x=1
Video encoding failed=-0.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:00.80 bitrate=26212.8kbits/s dup=29 drop=0 speed=1.58x   
Conversion failed!
```

Output from the version that doesnt work :

```
root@busplay4:/usr/bin# dpkg -l | grep ffmpeg
ii  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra           71.0.3578.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                armhf        Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
ii  ffmpeg                                 5:201812261919-git-1                         armhf        Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2
ii  ffmpeg-doc                             7:3.3.3-5ubuntu1                             all          Documentation of the FFmpeg multimedia framework
ii  ffmpegthumbnailer                      2.0.10-0.1                                   armhf        fast and lightweight video thumbnailer
ii  libavcodec-ffmpeg56:armhf              7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with de/encoders for audio/video codecs - runtime files
ii  libavdevice-ffmpeg56:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for handling input and output devices - runtime files
ii  libavfilter-ffmpeg5:armhf              7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library containing media filters - runtime files
ii  libavformat-ffmpeg56:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with (de)muxers for multimedia containers - runtime files
ii  libavresample-ffmpeg2:armhf            7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg compatibility library for resampling - runtime files
ii  libavutil-ffmpeg54:armhf               7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with functions for simplifying programming - runtime files
ii  libffmpegthumbnailer4v5                2.0.10-0.1                                   armhf        shared library for ffmpegthumbnailer
ii  libpostproc-ffmpeg53:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for post processing - runtime files
ii  libswresample-ffmpeg1:armhf            7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for audio resampling, rematrixing etc. - runtime files
ii  libswscale-ffmpeg3:armhf               7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for image scaling and various conversions - runtime files
```

Output from from working XU4

```
odroid@odroid:~$ dpkg  --list | grep "ffmpeg"
ii  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra           71.0.3578.98-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                armhf        Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
ii  ffmpeg                                 7:3.3.3-5ubuntu1                             armhf        Tools for transcoding, streaming and playing of multimedia files
ii  ffmpeg-doc                             7:3.3.3-5ubuntu1                             all          Documentation of the FFmpeg multimedia framework
ii  ffmpegthumbnailer                      2.0.10-0.1                                   armhf        fast and lightweight video thumbnailer
ii  libavcodec-ffmpeg56:armhf              7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with de/encoders for audio/video codecs - runtime files
ii  libavdevice-ffmpeg56:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for handling input and output devices - runtime files
ii  libavfilter-ffmpeg5:armhf              7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library containing media filters - runtime files
ii  libavformat-ffmpeg56:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with (de)muxers for multimedia containers - runtime files
ii  libavresample-ffmpeg2:armhf            7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg compatibility library for resampling - runtime files
ii  libavutil-ffmpeg54:armhf               7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library with functions for simplifying programming - runtime files
ii  libffmpegthumbnailer4v5                2.0.10-0.1                                   armhf        shared library for ffmpegthumbnailer
ii  libpostproc-ffmpeg53:armhf             7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for post processing - runtime files
ii  libswresample-ffmpeg1:armhf            7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for audio resampling, rematrixing etc. - runtime files
ii  libswscale-ffmpeg3:armhf               7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    armhf        FFmpeg library for image scaling and various conversions - runtime files
```

Also suggest if the errors arent because of the version change and logs suggest something else related to ffmpeg.

Comment: See comment in [How to rollback ffmpeg version to desired version? Is rollback needed in this scenario?](https://superuser.com/q/1392845/110524) crosspost.

Answer (score 2):

You need the source files to uninstall the wrong version.
Go to FFmpeg source folder and use the command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

It will uninstall the FFmpeg version that you don't need.